# JavaScript в Symfony. Взаимодействие back-end с JS

Tags: php, javascript, symfony2, doctrine2, symfony3

Всем привет. Впервые сталкиваюсь с работой JS в симфони. Занимаюсь только по части бэка, и возник вопрос. Имеется мини-игра написанная на JS. Прилагаю некоторую часть кода, которую нужно обработать:

```
if (found == 15) {
            msg = '<span id="msg">Поздравляем , вы победили! </span>';
            $("span.link").prepend(msg);
        }
```

После данного события нужно вносить в таблицу данные. А именно несколько переменных. Как вообще лучше это делать, посредством чего? Не очень понимаю как обрабатывать вообще JS код в Symfony в контроллере. Например, в JS есть три переменных которые я хочу внести в таблицу. Но как их обработать? В какую сторону смотреть?

Answer (score 0):

Я делаю это по средсвтом POST запроса. 
К примеру у меня есть контролер и в котором описано общая логика и формирования предстовление.
На стороне представления есть некий код JS который по итогу должен передать мне  данные для записи их в БД. Когда JS готов передать данные он отправляет их формате JSON через POST запрос на обрабочик (выделенный метод в классе.)

Ну а дальше все как обычно анализируем $request и записываем данные в БД.

Answer (score 0):

В контроллере Symfony, js-код не обрабатывается, он может подключаться в шаблонизаторе, который находится в папке `src/YourBandle/.../Resources/views/.../your_template.html.twig`.

Или, если вы отнаследовали шаблон от главного, можно js подключить в `app/Resources/views/your_template.html.twig`.

Рекомендую почитать, как подключаются скрипты через [assetic](http://symfony.com/doc/current/assetic/asset_management.html) (на русском нашёл только [это](https://folkprog.net/ispol-zovanie-assetic-v-sf/) ), но для начала можно подключить скрипты вставив обычный тег скрипта.

```
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/PATH_TO_JS/your.js">
    </script>
```

Сам js можно положить в папку web, которая в корне сайта, но правильно бы было подключать в том бандле где выводится данная страница в папке Resources, ну в js отправлять данные на Ваш контроллер аяксом